# Управление select в materializecss

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize-css

Возникла такая задача: при нажатии на кнопку надо сбрасывать select на значение null. Но, так как я использую materializecss, как это сделать по средствам Jquery я не соображу. Как это сделать?

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="null">Выберети число</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="btn">Изменить</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Css фреймворк никакого отношения к делу не имеет.

Comment: $select.val("null")?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно обновить селект:

```
 //после того, как сбросили <select>
 $('select').material_select('destroy');//уничтожаем
 $('select').material_select();//заново создаем materialize select
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function resetSelect()
{
  $("#select-1").find("option[value=null]").prop('selected', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="select-1">
      <option value="null">Выберети число</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="javascript:resetSelect()" class="btn">Изменить</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Твой код не работает. В materialize select создается с помощью jquery.

Comment: $("#select-1").find("option[value=null]").prop('selected', true); $("#select-1").trigger('change'); Вот так должно работать. Если нет, нужно смотреть не код из вопроса, а код, который волучается уже в materialize